# Error : Insert Failed :INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, Sharing Rule Trigger

Tags: security, sharing, user, apex-sharing

I have created one Trigger to give access to particular Accounts of my "Special" custom object records,

Here **BBB :** Is custom object having lookup of both Account and Special
E.g. BBBRecord = ( BBBName="Test",   Account=lookup of account,    Special = lookup of special
So, I want to give access to that selected Special record to the selected Account Owner !!

See following Code :

```
  List<Special_Share> lstShare = new List<Special_Share>();

    for(BBBB__c objBBB : Trigger.new ) {
        if( objBBB.MyAccount__c != NULL ) {

            Special__Share objS= new Special__Share();
            objS.AccessLevel = 'Edit';
            objS.parentID = objBBB.Specification__c;     // Set the ID of record being shared.

            // Assign user id to grant read write access to this particular Special record.
            ID accownerid = [select ownerid from Account where ID=:objBBB.MyAccount__c].OwnerId;
            objS.UserOrGroupId = accownerid;

            lstShare.add(objS);
        }
    }
  try{
    insert lstShare;
  }catch(Exception e){
    trigger.new[0].MyAccount__c.addError('Error::::::'+e.getMessage());
}
```

---

**ERROR :** :Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

---

Comment: Are they both lookup fields or master detail fields?

Comment: One of this is Lookup --MyAccount and  One is Master detail --- Special

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of things you are going to want to change. First off, it is a bad practice to include a [SOQL query inside of a `for` loop](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops). Secondly, the way you are handling the [error in the exception handler doesn't make sense](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling). The error may not be in the first record the Trigger runs through so it doesn't make sense to always include it there. Finally, you will want to set the `RowCause` field on the `Special__Share` record. It is a required field when using [Apex Managed Sharing](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm). It may be a good idea to read up on [Understanding Sharing](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm) as well.

Finally, if adding the RowCause doesn't work, you need to ensure that `Special__c` isn't the child of a [master-detail](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/relationships_among_objects.htm). Master-detail records inherit sharing from the master. You will also want to check that the [Org Wide Defaults](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_owd_about.htm&language=en_US) are not set to `Public Read/Write`. This won't allow sharing as well as everyone will already have access.